# facet_zoom() while setting axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I would like to use `facet_zoom()` to zoom in on part of an axis that has limits explicitly set. However, using `scale_*(limits = *)` and `coord_cartesian(xlim = *)` overrides the zoomed facet's scales as well such that both have the same limits. Is there a way around this? Maybe I could add some data points near the limits and then set their `alpha = 0`... Any other ideas?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
```

```r
# works with no limits specified
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cyl)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(20, 25))
```

[image: success case]

```r
# fails with limits specified
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cyl)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 50)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(20, 25))
```

[image: failure case 1]

```r
# fails with coord_cartesian()
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cyl)) + 
  scale_x_continuous() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 50)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(20, 25))
```

[image: failure case 2]

Comment: Looks like this is an open issue on ggforce's [Github repo](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/137). You could comment or +1 the issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough knowledge of the underlying intricacies in `FacetZoom`, but you can check if the following workarounds provide a reasonable starting point.

## Plot for demonstration

[image]

One of the key differences between setting limits in `scales_*` vs. `coord_*` is the clipping effect (screenshot taken from the ggplot2 cheatsheet found [here](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf)). Since this effect isn't really clear in a scatterplot, I added a `geom_line` layer and adjusted the specified limits so that the limits extend beyond the data range on one end of the x-axis, & clips the data on the other end.

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(colour = fl), size = 2) +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(20, 25)) +
  theme_bw()

# normal zoomed plot / zoomed plot with limits set in scale / coord
p0 <- p
p1 <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 35))
p2 <- p + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 35))
```

[image: demo plots]

We can see that while p0 behaves as expected, both p1 & p2 show both the original facet (top) & the zoomed facet (bottom) with the same range of `c(0, 35)`.

In p1's case, the shaded box also expanded to cover the entire top facet. In p2's case, the zoom box stayed in exactly the same position as p0, & as a result no longer covers the zoomed range of `c(20, 25)`.

## Workaround for limits set in `scale_*`

```
# convert ggplot objects to form suitable for rendering
gp0 <- ggplot_build(p0)
gp1 <- ggplot_build(p1)

# re-set zoomed facet's limits to match zoomed range
k <- gp1$layout$layout$SCALE_X[gp1$layout$layout$name == "x"]
gp1$layout$panel_scales_x[[k]]$limits <- gp1$layout$panel_scales_x[[k]]$range$range 

# re-set zoomed facet's panel parameters based on original version p0
k <- gp1$layout$layout$PANEL[gp1$layout$layout$name == "x"]
gp1$layout$panel_params[[k]] <- gp0$layout$panel_params[[k]]

# convert built ggplot object to gtable of grobs as usual & print result
gt1 <- ggplot_gtable(gp1)
grid::grid.draw(gt1)
```

[image: plot with limits set in scale]

The zoomed facet now shows the zoomed range `c(20, 25)` correctly, while the shaded box **shrinks** to cover the correct range in the original facet. Since this method **removes** unseen data points, all lines in the original facet stay **within** the confines of the facet.

## Workaround for limits set in `coord_*`

```
# convert ggplot objects to form suitable for rendering
gp0 <- ggplot_build(p0)
gp1 <- ggplot_build(p1)

# apply coord limits to original facet's scale limits
k <- gp2$layout$layout$SCALE_X[gp2$layout$layout$name == "orig"]
gp2$layout$panel_scales_x[[k]]$limits <- gp2$layout$coord$limits$x

# re-set zoomed facet's panel parameters based on original version without setting
# limits in scale
k <- gp1$layout$layout$PANEL[gp1$layout$layout$name == "x"]
gp2$layout$panel_params[[k]] <- gp0$layout$panel_params[[k]]

# convert built ggplot object to gtable of grobs as usual,
# & print result
gt2 <- ggplot_gtable(gp2)
grid::grid.draw(gt2)
```

[image: plot with limits set in coord]

The zoomed facet now shows the zoomed range `c(20, 25)` correctly, while the shaded box **shifts** to cover the correct range in the original facet. Since this method **includes** unseen data points, some lines in the original facet extend **beyond** the facet's confines.

*Note: These workarounds should work with zoom in y + limits set in y-axis as well, as long as all references to `"x"` / `panel_scales_x` / `SCALE_X` above are changed to `"y"` / `panel_scales_y` / `SCALE_Y`. I haven't tested this for other combinations such as zoom in both x & y, but the broad principle ought to be similar.*